# Incomplete message sent from SIM900D GSM Module using Python and Arduino

Tags: android, python

I am reading lines from a text file using python and then sending the strings via serial port to arduino UNO. The strings are then passed on to the SIM900D GSM Module which sends these strings as 01 consolidated text message to a number of my choosing. The problem is that the code is working fine for the first 06 lines of the text message. However, if I add a 7th line then I do not receive an SMS.

The python code is as follows:

```
import os, time, shutil, serial, sys, glob                  
source_fld = "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Processing";                 #source folder
dest_fld = "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Processed";                    #destination folder

os.chdir('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Processing')                     #change to current working directory
filenames = os.listdir(os.curdir)                                   #put all the names of the files in a string

lines_counter = 0                                                  #for all the lines of the message
my_body = [lines_counter]                                              #declaring an array

for filename in filenames:                                          #use for loop for opening the files by extension
    arduino = serial.Serial("COM3",9600,timeout = 5)                #initializing the arduino
    time.sleep(2)                                                   #2 seconds of sleep time
    arduino.flush()                                                 #clear the internal buffer with flush
    text_file = open(filename, "r")                                 #opening the text file
    my_string = text_file.readline()                                #reading the lines from the text file
    st_string = my_string.strip("\n")                               #strip the new line character from the end of the string   
    numbers = st_string.split(",")                                  #split the comma seperated values in the contact numbers field  
    size = len(numbers)                                             #find out the length of the array
    sizerange = 0                                                   #To start the counter from zero

    while (sizerange != size):                                      #while loop for printing out the values of the contact numbers array one by one

        sum_num = numbers                                           #declaring a seperate array for manipulation
        sum_num[sizerange] = numbers[sizerange].strip("\n") + "\r"  #stripping the new line character from each element of the array and adding carriage return
        print(sum_num[sizerange])                                   #array elements printing okay
        #arduino.write(sum_num[sizerange])                           #write the data to arduino
        sizerange = sizerange + 1                                   #increment the value of sizerange

    trip = str(size)
    print(trip)
    arduino.write(trip)                                             #sending the size of array
    time.sleep(1)

    line1 = text_file.readline()
    arduino.write(line1)
    time.sleep(2)

    line2 = text_file.readline()                                      
    arduino.write(line2)
    time.sleep(2)

    line3 = text_file.readline()                                      
    arduino.write(line3)
    time.sleep(2)

    line4 = text_file.readline()                                      
    arduino.write(line4)
    time.sleep(2)

    line5 = text_file.readline()                                      
    arduino.write(line5)
    time.sleep(2)

    line6 = text_file.readline()
    arduino.write(line6)
    time.sleep(2)


    arduino.close()

    text_file.close()                                               #closing the text file
    time.sleep(2)                                                   #sleep for 2 seconds    

for txt_file in glob.glob(source_fld+"\\*.txt"):                    #moving all the text files to destination folder
    shutil.move(txt_file, dest_fld)
print("All files have been moved")    

sys.exit()                                                              #kill the python function
```

The Arduino Code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8);
String msg_counter;
String msg_line1,msg_line2,msg_line3,msg_line4,msg_line5,msg_line6,msg_line7,msg_line8,msg_line9,msg_line10,msg_line11,msg_line12,msg_line13,msg_line14,msg_line15;
int counter;
int do_it = 1;

void setup() {

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  while(!Serial.available()){}      //stay here until there is data available on the Serial port
  while(Serial.available()){
    if(Serial.available()>0){
      msg_counter = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line1 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line2 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line3 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line4 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line5 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
      msg_line6 = Serial.readString();
      delay(2000);
    }
  }
counter = msg_counter.toInt();
if(counter == 2){ 
  SendMessage();
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); 
}


}

void SendMessage()
{
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+9XXXXXXXXXXX\"\r"); 
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println(msg_line1);
  mySerial.println(msg_line2);
  mySerial.println(msg_line3);
  mySerial.println(msg_line4);
  mySerial.println(msg_line5);
  mySerial.println(msg_line6);
  //mySerial.println(msg_line7);
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}
```

The text file I am reading has the following contents:

```
AT+CMGS="0xxxxxxxxxx",AT+CMGS="0xxxxxxxxxx"
Dear Customer,
Following Call has been logged:
Call No:   1151
Call Created : 8/30/2017 4:07:02 PM
Customer: INOR
Equipment Name: SOMATOM Emotion
Equipment Serial No: 93851
Issue Description: Commissioning data, PPM.
CSE: Imran Khan
Contract Status: Warranty

Regards,
ABCD Customer Care Center
UAN:  +92 42 111 74 36 36
Email:  hc.customercare.pk@abcd.com
```

Can anyone suggest what seems to be the problem? Is there any limitation of the SIM900D regarding the number of lines and characters that can be sent in an SMS?